# React plot options onclick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, onclick, react-highcharts

I have made a highcharts column chart in my react application, and am now trying to add an onClick event to the chart. My aim is that when the user click a column, I can obtain the values of the X and Y axis, and then call a function from the page.

The onClick event is achieved using plotoptions, as follows:

```
plotOptions={{
  series: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
      events: {
        click: () => {
          this.fuction.call(this, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

The problem with this is that I can call the function, but I cannot access the values of the column.

So, I try this:

```
plotOptions={{
  series: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function () {
          console.log(this);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

This way, I can access the values on the column, through `this` but cannot call the function, as this does not hold the current page object.

My question is, how can I combine the two, so I can access the value of the selected column and call the function on the page?

I have tried this:

```
plotOptions={{
  series: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function (e) {
          console.log(this);
          console.log(e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

Which gives me the onClick event, and the column, but not the current page object.

I have also tried this:

```
plotOptions={{
  column: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
      events: {
        click: (e) => { console.log(this); console.log(e);  }
      }
    }
  }                    
}}
```

But this also does not give me what I need.

I am sure this is not  very difficult, I just cannot find it, or the correct search term...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
plotOptions={{
  series: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
      events: {
        click: (e) => { console.log(this); console.log(e.point.category); console.log(e.point.y);  }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

Now `this` contains the current state of the page, and I can access the information from the column from `e.point`

Comment: what is I can't use 'this' because I use a function component?

Comment: @Shinji035 I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: I use react function component, so there is no 'this' keyword in function component .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
click: function(e) {
    console.log(
        e.yAxis[0].value, e.xAxis[0].value
    )
}
```

You may find more infos following this link :

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.click

Comment: You should add at least the core information that will be found behind the link, since once the link is broken, the information would not be available for any user.

Answer (score 0):

In plotOption click event is like this

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/faqaxocage/1/edit?html,js,console,output) demo

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    console.log('X: ' + this.x + ', Y: ' + this.y);
                    //call function passing this values as arguments
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```